# Pre-filling form data

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form using Symfony2. Here is an excerpt:

```
$comment = new Comment();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($comment)
    ->add('user_id', 'hidden')
    ->add('node_id', 'hidden')
    ->add('comment', 'textarea', [
        'attr' => [
            'style' => 'width:100%; background-color:inherit; color:white;',
                'rows' => '5'
            ]
        ])
    ->add('save', 'submit', ['label' => 'Send'])
    ->getForm();
```

(Note, these are just some of the fields, to keep it short.

Then I prefill some of the data in the form.

```
$form->get('user_id')->setData($user_id);
$form->get('node_id')->setData($video->getId());
```

But when I load the page, and fill out the `comment` field and submit, I get the error that `user_id` and `node_id` haven't been filled out.

What should I do about these? How should I render them? Can I render them with these preset values?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was just stupid of me, but I'll resist my urge to delete, and just answer instead.

If setting values in the controller, don't bother having them in the form at all.

```
$comment = new Comment();
$comment->setNodeId($video->getId());
$comment->setUserId($user_id);

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($comment)
    ->add('comment', 'textarea', [
        'attr' => [
        'style' => 'width:100%; background-color:inherit; color:white;',
            'rows' => '5'
        ]
    ])
->add('save', 'submit', ['label' => 'Send'])
->getForm();
```

In other words, just set the values directly on the object instead, and leave the form out of it. Leave that for values that need to come from the user.